# html and php form not sending / sending empty mails

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

So I have this small html form, now I wanted to use php to send rhe data to a e-mail.
for the form i used a template I changed a few names. 1 time it send an email but it was empty, from all the other tries I don't get a mail at all. from searching the internet I get that I've done nothing wrong, checked names and all.

html:

```
<div id="contact">
 <h1>Neem contact met ons op</h1>

<form class="cd-form floating-labels" action="form_sent.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <fieldset>
<div class="error-message">
      <p>Vul een geldig e-mailadres in</p>
            </div>

            <div class="icon">
                <label class="cd-label">Naam</label>
                <input class="user" type="text" name="cd-name" id="cd-name" required>
            </div> 

            <div class="icon">
                <label class="cd-label">Bedrijf</label>
                <input class="company" type="text" name="cd-company" id="cd-company">
            </div> 

            <div class="icon">
                <label class="cd-label">Email</label>
                <input class="email" type="email" name="cd-email" id="cd-email" required>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
<div> </div>
<div class="icon">
      <label class="cd-label">Bericht</label>
                <textarea class="message" name="cd-textarea" id="cd-textarea" required></textarea>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Verzenden">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

php:

```
<?php

$user = $_POST['cd-user'];
$company = $_POST['cd-company'];
$email = $_POST['cd-email'];
$message = $_POST['cd-textarea'];

$to = "van_vliet@wxs.nl";
$subject = "Website bericht";

mail ($to , $subject , $message, "From: " , $user , $company , $email);

echo "Bedankt voor uw bericht";
?>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's your problem, but on the line `<div> </div>` you should remove the `<div>`. Also adding a `</div>` at the very end, double check your structure and make sure every opening/closing tag is in the correct place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong arguments to mail(). It expects 5, 2 of them optional:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

In your case, I think the last 3 parameters are only one, so do this:

```
$userInfo = $user." ".$company." <".$email.">";
mail ($to , $subject , $message, "From: ".$userInfo);
```

Also, for $user you're getting $_POST["cd-user"], but the input `name` is `cd-name`, not `cd-user`

--

The problem ended up being that PHP can't handle enctype="text/plain", so removing it fixed it.

Comment: Thanks it kind of worked, the email is being sent but its still empty.

Comment: What is empty? The body? The subject? The From field?

Comment: the message that need to be sent

Comment: `$user = $_POST['cd-user'];` You're trying to get this but `cd-user` doesn't exist. Again, you need to double check all of your tags/attribute values.

Comment: @LaurensvanVliet but is the subject set, for example?

Comment: subject is working, it's the message it just doesn't get trough

Comment: And what are you inputting in cd-textarea?

Comment: textarea is the field where the user can put in his message to us. also I ask them to put in their name and company they're from. also that doesn't show up.

Comment: Hmm, so the only thing that does work is the subject, which is hardcoded. It seems like you're not getting the values from $_POST. Can you try getting them with $_REQUEST to narrow it down? Put something like var_dump($_POST);var_dump($_REQUEST); at the top of the PHP file.

Comment: @ishegg tried putting var_dump($POST) at the top, but the mail is still empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152086/discussion-between-ishegg-and-laurens-van-vliet).